# how to build a widget in a stack instead of using Visibility widget to show/hide it

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and have built an app where it uses the visibility widget to show/hide widgets. I understand this is not very optimal but I'm struggling to get my head around the build function to build a widget when a button is pressed.

currently, I have the below code which is a button that when pressed, shows a menu of buttons and when one is pressed, it then writes the selections text to a string variable (displayText) that is displayed on the original button.

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String displayText = 'Choose option';
  bool menuVisibility = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      menuVisibility = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$displayText',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: menuVisibility,
            child: OptionMenu(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  displayText = val;
                  menuVisibility = false;
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the OptionMenu() code:

```
class OptionMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  OptionMenu({required this.onTap});
  final ValueChanged? onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Button(text: 'Option A', onTap: onTap),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Button(text: 'Option B', onTap: onTap),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Button(text: 'Option C', onTap: onTap),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Button(text: 'Option D', onTap: onTap),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and finally, here is the Button() code:

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  Button({required this.text, required this.onTap});
  final String text;
  final ValueChanged? onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (onTap != null) {
          onTap!(text);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So what I'm wanting to do is instead of using the visibility widget, I'd like it to build the Option Menu widget in the stack when I press the original button and then when I make my choice from the menu, have the menu disappear and the string variable, displayText update to the new selection.

Thanks so much and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of Visibility widget, here is simple hack just replace the Visibility widget with **if** statement

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String displayText = 'Choose option';
  bool menuVisibility = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      menuVisibility = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$displayText',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
         if(menuVisibility)
           OptionMenu(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  displayText = val;
                  menuVisibility = false;
                });
              },
           ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. this is a good option to replace the visibility widget. what I'm trying to do though is when the button is pressed, I want to insert a specific widget into the build tree. My original code has a very long optionMenu list and many choices to choose from and my code is becoming spaghetti. hence why i'd like to learn how to insert a specific widget into a specific container when a button is pressed. thanks so much